# psycopg2 - Inserting an integer array

Tags: psycopg2

I'm using Postgres 9.2, Python 2.7.3, psycopg2 2.5.1.

I have a table, with one of the fields declared as 'some_field int[] NOT NULL' and I need to insert some data, so I'm doing something like this:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO some_table (some_field) VALUES (%s)', ([1, 2, 3], ))
```

but unexpectedly getting an error 'DataError: missing "]" in array dimensions', because the result query becames

```
INSERT INTO some_table (some_field) VALUES ('[1, 2, 3]')
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO some_table (some_field) VALUES (ARRAY[1, 2, 3])
```

or

```
INSERT INTO some_table (some_field) VALUES ('{1, 2, 3}')
```

Am I missing something or it is a psycopg2 error?

Answer (score 9):

The first snippet of code is the correct one. To check the SQL generated by psycopg2 you can always use the `mogrify()` method:

```
>>> curs.mogrify('INSERT INTO some_table (some_field) VALUES (%s)', ([1, 2, 3], ))
'INSERT INTO some_table (some_field) VALUES (ARRAY[1, 2, 3])'
```

Then you can try the SQL using `psql` and look for errors. If you find that psycopg2 generates a query that can't be executed in `psql`, please report a bug.