# SQL psycopg2 insert variable that is a list of variable length into database

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

I am trying to write a row of observations into my database, but I have some unique variable called list_variable which is a list of strings that can be of length 1-3. So sometimes ['string1'] but sometimes also ['string1','string2'] or ['string1','string2','string3'].

When I try to add this to my database by:

```
def add_to_cockroach_db():
        cur.execute(f"""
        INSERT INTO database (a, b, c)
        VALUES ({time.time()}, {event},{list_variable};  <--- this one
        """)
        conn.commit()
```

I would get the following error (values have been changed for readability):

```
SyntaxError: at or near "[": syntax error
DETAIL:  source SQL:
INSERT INTO database (a, b, c)
        VALUES (a_value, b_value, ['c_value_1', 'c_value_2'])
                                  ^
HINT:  try \h VALUES
```

It seems that having a variable that is a list is not allowed, how could I make this work out?

Thanks in advance!

**edit

list_variable looks e.g., like this = ['value1','value2']

Comment: Do you want to write it to your database as a string or create one new row for every value in your list?

Comment: try to convert your list to string.  {str(list_variable)}

Comment: Do not create the SQL statement yourself, psycopg does it for you https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [psycopg2 - Inserting an integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815302/psycopg2-inserting-an-integer-array)

Comment: @bitflip i want it to be one row!

Comment: @snakecharmerb it is a list of strings!

Comment: I mean what is the type of the column _in the database table_.

Comment: @snakecharmerb ah sorry, It is a STRING NOT NULL, perhaps here something else can be chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either cast it to string using

```
str(['c_value_1', 'c_value_2'])
```

which looks like this:

```
"['c_value_1', 'c_value_2']"
```

or join the elements of your list with a delimiter you choose. This for example generates a comma separated string.

```
",".join(['c_value_1', 'c_value_2'])
```

which looks like this:

```
'c_value_1,c_value_2'
```

Like Maurice Meyer has already pointed out in the comments, it is better to pass your values as a list or as a tuple instead of formatting the query yourself.
Your command could look like this depending on the solution you choose:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO database (a, b, c) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (time.time(), event, ",".join(list_variable)))
```

Comment: If i try str(list_variable) i get: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: what types do the values in your list have?

Comment: they are strings in a list! I have added some info to the post above

Comment: Okay, could you post the modified query one more time?

Comment: i got it working, it was due to a comma that was there after (a, b, c) VALUES,  <---

Comment: okay, great! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could accomplish this.

The simplest way is to call `str` on the list and insert the result into a string ([VARCHAR](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html)) column. While this works, it's not easy to work with the values in database queries, and when it's retrieved from the database it's a string, not a list.

Using a [VARCHAR[]](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) column type - an array of string values - reflects the actual data type, and enables use of PostgreSQL's [array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) in queries.

Finally, you could use a [JSONB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) column type. This allows storage of lists or dicts, or nested combinations of both, so it's very flexible, and PostgreSQL provides [functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) for working with JSON objects too.  However it might be overkill if you don't need the flexibility, or if you want to be strict about the data.

This script shows all three methods in action:

```py
import psycopg2                                                   
from psycopg2.extras import Json                                   

DROP = """DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t73917632"""  
CREATE = """\                                                       
CREATE TABLE t73917632 (
    s VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    a VARCHAR[] NOT NULL,                    
    j JSONB NOT NULL                         
)
"""
INSERT = """INSERT INTO t73917632 (s, a, j) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"""
SELECT = """SELECT s, a, j FROM t73917632"""
                                             
v = ['a', 'b', 'c']                          
                                             
with psycopg2.connect(dbname='test') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(DROP)  
        cur.execute(CREATE)
        conn.commit()                                                                       
        cur.execute(INSERT, (str(v), v, Json(v)))
        conn.commit()                                                                       
        cur.execute(SELECT)                                                                 
        for row in cur:                                                                     
            print(row)
```

Output:

```
("['a', 'b', 'c']", ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

It's worth observing that if the array of strings represents some kind of child relationship to the table - for example the table records teams, and the string array contains the names of team members - it is usually a better design to insert each element in the array into a separate row in a child table, and associate them with the parent row using a foreign key.